# Is there such a problem as b-Matching with different b values?

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs, matching, bipartite-matching

Consider a bipartite Garph $G=(L \cup R, E)$. Naturally, a b-Matching problem is to find a set of edges $M \subset E$, such that each node in $L$ and $R$ are adjuscent to maximum $b$ neighbors, and a weight function $w(e), e \in E$ is maximized.
What if we have different $b$? e.g., $b(v)=5, \forall v \in R$ and $b(v)=2, \forall v \in L$. How do you call the problem? Is is constrained matching, or k-cardinality assignment, or what? I need to find some literature for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's a standard problem, but it seems this problem is described in [Solving the Many to Many assignment problem by improving the Kuhn–Munkres algorithm with backtracking](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397516000037).

(the other closest things I found are https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_assignment_problem and https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02190106.pdf, but they are talking about one-to-many assignments).

Anyway, you can solve it using maximum flow. For $b=1$ (usual matching) you can check [these slides](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/matching.pdf), namely this picture:
[image]

I.e. we create auxiliary vertices $s$ and $t$, create edges $(s, u)$ for all $u$ in the left part and $(v, t)$ for all $v$ in the right part. All edges have capacity one. By solving maximum flow on this graph, you'll find maximum matching (Note: you have to find an integral solution, i.e. where flow through each edge is either 1 or 0, but standard maximum flow algorithms will do that).

For $b>1$ the graph is the same. The difference is that all edges $(s,u)$ have capacity $b_L$ and $(v,t)$ have capacity $b_R$.

If your edges have weights, then you can negate edge weights and solve min-cost max-flow on this graph.